# Ethereum I want to find it

Tags: addresses, ico

During the course of the Tezos ICO,

By mistake, send the Tezos ICO addresses Ethereum at the Bithumb exchange exchange address.

It's vaporized.

Is there any way I can find it?

Please help me.

Comment: May I disturb you for a little? I lost Private Key + JSON file to open my myEtherwallet.com. Do you know how to find: - What time is a MEW wallet created?
- What website that has created an Ethereum wallet? (This is because I am not sure I had created this MEW from www.myetherwallet.com)
- I still keep its Password, is there any chance to recover my MEW? Many thanks to you!
Quiet Mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find the transaction (on EtherScan for example), you may be able to send it to technical support at the exchange and try to convince them that you incorrectly sent the ether. They may send it back.

My guess is they won't because how can they really know what you meant to do, but maybe it's worth a try. And...importantly...the kindness of strangers is the only possible way to get your ether back. There is no technical way to get it back.

I have nothing to do with the exchange, nor am I saying anything with any conviction, just that this is your only recourse.

Answer (score 0):

No. Sorry, but you can't cancel a transaction.